# Проблемы с выводом списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

Есть проблемка, есть скрипт который выводит список доступного оборудования. Если в списке значений больше 60, он просто ложится.

Вот на что ругается питон:

```
File "CursesList.py", line 84, in print_options
    self.screen.addstr(loc[0], loc[1], print_str)
_curses.error: addwstr() returned ERR
```

Код который присутствует там:

```
for i, item in enumerate(self.data):
    loc = (i + num_header_rows, 0)
    if i == self.active_choice:
        print_str, args = self.write_func(item, active=True)
        self.active_ip = item.split()[0]
    else:
        print_str, args = self.write_func(item)
    if args:
        self.screen.addstr(loc[0], loc[1], print_str, args)
    else:
        self.screen.addstr(loc[0], loc[1], print_str)   # <-- Это 84 строчка.
```

Comment: в тексте ошибки написано, в чем причина

Comment: @Эникейщик, так он может английский не знает